# Transaction Log Ordering

Tags: paypal, transactions

I'm working with PayPal transaction logs and finding that the ordering is only really accurate down to the minute; if several transactions occur within the same minute then the real order of processing is lost, based on time.

Is there any was to obtain logs down to the millisecond, or a method for ordering based on transaction ID?

thanks

Comment: But the logs , do you mean the transaction details ?

Comment: When you download the transaction history

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the "[GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)" API to get all the information related to that transaction . Below is the sample request and response .

**NVP Request:**

```
USER=XXXXXX&PWD=XXXXXXXX&SIGNATURE=XXXX&VERSION=109.0&METHOD=GetTransactionDetails&TRANSACTIONID=9SM883109X808705E
```

**NVP Response:**

```
RECEIVERBUSINESS=XXXXXXXXXXX
RECEIVEREMAIL=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
RECEIVERID=XXXXXXXXXX
PAYERID=RPP8F58J274JG
PAYERSTATUS=unverified
COUNTRYCODE=US
ADDRESSOWNER=PayPal
ADDRESSSTATUS=None
SALESTAX=0.00
SHIPAMOUNT=0.00
SHIPHANDLEAMOUNT=0.00
TIMESTAMP=2014-11-21T23:00:52Z
CORRELATIONID=a53ad76aa9f83
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=13834430
FIRSTNAME=John
LASTNAME=Smith
TRANSACTIONID=9SM883109X808705E
RECEIPTID=1388-0302-9236-9276
TRANSACTIONTYPE=webaccept
PAYMENTTYPE=instant
ORDERTIME=2014-10-20T21:58:02Z
AMT=10.00
TAXAMT=0.00
CURRENCYCODE=AUD
PAYMENTSTATUS=Expired
PENDINGREASON=None
REASONCODE=None
PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY=Ineligible
PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE=None
L_QTY0=1
L_TAXAMT0=0.00
L_CURRENCYCODE0=AUD
L_TAXABLE0=false
```

Comment: Doesn't address the requirement - the Timestamp field in your example still only goes to the second - multiple transactions in the same second therefore are not guaranteed to be returned in the correct order.  This also assumes you have all the transaction IDs in the first place, which as far as I can see, is not possible to get a history between a date range through the API.. unless there is, in which case that would be useful... though still would not address the granularity issue.

Comment: The other way if not using time stamps would be to be able to decode the transaction ID to an big int to infer sequence, assuming transaction IDs are a sequence